# Why is cross_val_score not producing consistent results?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

When this code executes the results are not consistent.
Where is the randomness coming from?

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

seed = 42
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

pipeline = Pipeline([('std', StandardScaler()), 
                     ('pca', PCA(n_components = 4)), 
                     ('Decision_tree', DecisionTreeClassifier())], 
                    verbose = False)

kfold = KFold(n_splits = 10, random_state = seed, shuffle = True)
results = cross_val_score(pipeline, X, y, cv = kfold)
print(results.mean())


0.9466666666666667
0.9266666666666665
0.9466666666666667
0.9400000000000001
0.9266666666666665
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DecisionTreeClassifier` does not use all columns, but by default the sqrt of the number of columns for each split. You assigned the seed to `KFold`, but not to `DecisionTreeClassifier`. So different columns will be selected each run. `PCA` also accepts a random state.

See [DecisionTreeClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier) and [PCA](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html)